# Can I register devices from a backend or only from the apps?

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

the thing is that we already have a backend that handles all the push notification process. From device registration on our DB and notification handling on the device and notification sending to Apple and Google servers...Looking into Parse I saw that it has a lot of things that will take us a lot of time to develop but mostly on the process that sends the notification to the devices.

So...I need to know if devices can register in our backend, then from our backend to Parse and then send push trough Parse. Is this possible? Image below.

Thanks!!

[image: What we need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  You'll need setup your push certificates with Parse and register each device's push token with a Parse Installation object's deviceToken field for it to work.  All this is documented on their web site.  You'll need to setup a Parse User object for each user as well as each Installation is associated with a single User.